# IBM Trusteer Rapport... Daemons... Is rapportd part of Trusteer or an Apple MacOS Daemon?

Tags: macos, daemons

Working here on problems arising from IBM Trusteer Rapport security software.

Problem: Their daemon rooksd has 60,000 ports open; mac slowed to a crawl.

Question: Is the daemon rapportd part of Trusteer or is it an Apple MacOS daemon? Other comments here say it's Apple. But, IBM Trusteer support says it's theirs.

Comment: My daemon is /usr/libexec/rapportd    and is signed by Apple.  Based on that, I think I can be sure it's Apple, and not IBM Trusteer, right?

Comment: Malware and even some legitimate software (I’ll leave you to classify IBM’s offering) often uses the same name to confuse people. Can you specify a specific path or process so we know which daemon / process you are observing? An edit to the question will help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

rapportd, or at least `/usr/libexec/rapportd`, is an Apple macOS daemon. From the man page:

> Daemon that enables Phone Call Handoff and other communication features between Apple devices.

By examining RapportUninstaller.sh, the expected locations for Trusteer Rapport's rapportd are:

- `/Library/Rapport/bin/rapportd.app/Contents/MacOS/rapportd`
- `/Library/Rapport/bin/rapportd`

Comment: First, big thanks for clear answer from grg.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, be aware that IBM  Trusteer continues to insist that the daemon /usr/libexec/rapportd belongs to Trusteer Rapport (even though it's signed by Apple). I'll believe grg and not Trusteer support. Disappointing that they are giving the wrong answer.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the correct answer is:  /usr/libexec/rapportd, is an Apple macOS daemon.